# Matplotlib x axis

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have the following issue with `matplotlib`. I have this Numpy-Matrix and now I plot `plt.plot(wp[:, 0])` the first column which works flawlessly. Now on the x-axis I have written `(1..2..3..4..5..6..7..8..9)` (for this example))

But instead I would like to have there `(0.1..2...3.4)` So it should display me the current value of the second column. (The size of `wp` varies, so I need a general solution..)

```
wp=[[x1,0],
[x2,1],
[x3,1],
[x4,2],
[x5,2],
[x6,2],    
[x7,3],
[x8,3],
[x9,4]]
```

Edit: Sorry, I made a huge mistake, when I was lazy and created the example matrix. The x-values are all different.
Edit2: To be more precise. In this example the x-value of x1 should be 0, and the stick also 0. Then x2 should be right to x1 and should have the x-tick 1. x3 should be right to x2 and there should be no x-tick displayed. x4 should be right of x3 and there should be the x-tick 2, and so forth. So it should be plotted like plt.plot(wp[:, 0]) does, but on the x-axis I want to see in which area, the second column is 0 or 1 or 2 or ...

Comment: What's preventing you from using the second column as the X values?

Comment: So you want to have all your second elements from your tuple as your x-tick labels?

Comment: @The Predator. Thats correct, but all for example [x3,1] [x4,1] should not have the same x-value!

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# creating random values for x1,x2 and x3
x1 = 1
x2 = 2
x3 = 3

wp=[[x1,0],
[x2,1],
[x3,1],
[x1,2],
[x2,2],
[x3,2],    
[x1,3],
[x2,3],
[x3,4]]


my_xticks = [x[1] for x in wp] # taking the second values from tuple
my_xticks = list(set(my_xticks)) # removing duplicates

# In [16]: my_xticks
# Out[16]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] # values of my_xticks after removing duplicates


x = [x[0] for x in wp]
y = x

plt.xticks(my_xticks)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, when I tried to explain my problem. See Edit